# Controller tests for RESTful actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, bdd

Although I generally use the Fat Model, Skinny Controller approach I can see the point of testing complicated controller actions, but I'm wondering: Is there any reason to write controller tests for the RESTful actions generated by rails scaffolding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply Put: If you have code in your application, maintained by you, test that code.

I avoid writing tests for actions or behavior provided by InheritedResources or other REST gems, but once there is logic, especially redirect and authentication/resource ownership logic, it should be tested. Notably, the last time I used scaffold and rspec it generated all those tests for me as well.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, your controller specs or tests help to debug paths or values in an action. Often, you'll see:

```
@post = some_logic_gets_a_post
if @post.present?
   # happy path
else
   # failure path
end
```

With the controller tests you can make sure, you'll enter the right state under your assumptions, or that you hit the correct exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

In general I find it useful when testing authentication and authorization, at this point I don't really care what the content returns but more if I get the right redirects, status codes etc.

A second case where I value controller tests is when the controller can answer in more than one dialect. e.g. JSON, XML and/or HTML. However when the formats get complex it's better to do this with a builder and not hide this complexity in controllers.